# Showing the Minkowski force in the covariant form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces

So I would like to show

\begin{equation}
K^{\mu} = \frac{q}{c}F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \frac{q}{c}\left[\partial^{\mu}(A^{\nu}u_{\nu}) - \frac{dA^{\mu}}{d \tau}\right] 
\end{equation}

and I went about as follows:

I can re-write the electric and magnetic fields of

\begin{equation}
 \textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t) = -\nabla\Phi(\textbf{r},t) -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textbf{B}(\textbf{r},t) = \nabla \times \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t) 
\end{equation}

by employing the four-gradient notation to get

\begin{equation}
E^i = -(\partial^0A^i - \partial^iA^0) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B^i = -(\partial^jA^k - \partial^kA^j) 
\end{equation}

where the indices $(ijk)$ are cyclic permutations of $(123)$. I can find the contravariant electromagnetic field tensor by putting these expressions for the electric and magnetic fields together in matrix form as

\begin{equation}
F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

If I multiply this tensor with the four-velocity I get

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \gamma
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
-\dot{x} \\
-\dot{y} \\
-\dot{z}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\gamma
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{E} \cdot \textbf{r} \\
cE_x + \dot{y}B_z - \dot{z}B_y \\
cE_y + \dot{z}B_x - \dot{x}B_z \\
cE_z + \dot{x}B_y - \dot{y}B_x
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

which gives me

\begin{equation}
F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{E} \cdot \dot{\textbf{r}} \\
c\textbf{E} + \dot{\textbf{r}} \times \textbf{B}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I notice that the space component of the right-hand side is similar to the Lorentz force (minus some factors)

\begin{equation}
\textbf{F}_L = e\textbf{E} + \frac{e}{c}\dot{\textbf{r}} \times \textbf{B}
\end{equation}

I can find from this the form-invariant generalization of Newton’s second law for this case as

\begin{equation}
\frac{e}{c}F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \frac{d(mu^{\mu})}{d\tau}
\end{equation}

Now my question is this: I've been told the reasoning in the next step where I say that before I write the [Minkowski force](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=minkowski+force) given by the contracted field tensor I note that:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu})u_{\nu} = \partial^{\mu}(A^{\nu}u_{\nu}) - A^{\nu}\underbrace{\partial^{\nu}u_{\nu}}_\text{=0}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dA^{\mu}}{d\tau} = (\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu})\frac{dx_{\nu}}{d\tau} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial A^{\mu}}{\partial \tau}}_\text{=0}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

My reasoning for this is that the respective partial derivatives vanish because $u_{\nu}$ is not an explicit function of the spacial component $x_{\mu}$ and $A^{\mu}$ is not an explicit function of the time component $\tau$. I have been told however that there is an error in my argument here. From this reasoning I went on to say that I can write the Minkowski force as

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
K^{mu} = \frac{e}{c}F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \frac{e}{c}\left[\partial^{\mu}(A^{\nu}u_{\nu}) - \frac{dA^{\mu}}{d\tau}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

but that argument would not hold if my reasoning is incorrect.

tl;dr: Apparently my reasoning to get from

\begin{equation}
\frac{e}{c}F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \frac{d(mu^{\mu})}{d\tau}
\end{equation}

to

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
K^{mu} = \frac{e}{c}F^{\mu\nu}u_{\nu} = \frac{e}{c}\left[\partial^{\mu}(A^{\nu}u_{\nu}) - \frac{dA^{\mu}}{d\tau}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

is wrong, but I'm not seeing the problem. Does anyone on the stackexchange see my problem?

Comment: Duplicate : [Generalizing the Lorentz force law in 4-vector notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645124/generalizing-the-lorentz-force-law-in-4-vector-notation/645621#645621).

Comment: @Frobenius I am a bit confused as to how my question, posted over 3 years ago, is a "duplicate" of something asked 27 days ago. Ignoring that, it was also, unfortunately, 3 years ago. I don't necessarily think that post is entirely relevant, but wouldn't be able to say for sure since I'm certainly not in that class anymore. May be edifying for some other physics graduate in the future.

Comment: Community has activated your question in the front page some hours ago to inform users that your question has no answer accepted by you or at least upvoted once. Duplicate in our case means that an identical question already exists with at least a good answer upvoted and moreover accepted even 3 years later (see the  answer provided by @joigus). As to the "*I don't necessarily think that post is entirely relevant...*" let me insist that your question is identical to that : your 1st equation herein is identical to the 2nd one therein...

Comment: Duplicate does not mean that there was an omission or fault on your part.

Answer (score 0):

As 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dA^\mu}{d\tau} = d^\nu A^\mu \frac{dx_\nu}{d\tau} = d^\nu A^\mu u_\nu
\end{equation}
one has
\begin{equation}
F^{\mu\nu} u_\nu = d^\mu A^\nu u_\nu - d^\nu A^\mu u_\nu = d^\mu A^\nu u_\mu - \frac{dA^\mu}{d\tau} .
\end{equation}

Comment: So I'm confused by what your comment changes what I've done, since it looks like you defined dA^{\mu}/d\tau the same way that I did. If it's not too much, could you please explain your response?

Comment: Indeed $u^\mu$ is independent from $x^\mu$  and $A^\mu$ does not implicitly depend on $\tau$. Using these facts you will arrive at the derivation that I gave. Can you clarify the difficulty that you see with this ?